# Grid not complete display TextBlock when execute RenderTransform animation

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to make an animation:
Basicly I just want a `TextBlock` move from right to left.

This is the XAML file:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="grdTextblockParent">
            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="grdTransform"/>
            </Grid.RenderTransform>
            <TextBlock Text="This is a Test 1This is a Test 2This is a Test 3This is a Test 4This is a Test 5This is a Test 6This is a Test 7This is a Test 8This is a Test 9This is a Test 10"></TextBlock>

        </Grid>
        <Button  Width="75" Height="50" Content="Start" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

As you see, The TextBlock has so many :"this is a Test *(number)".
Now I add the animation in the background.

```
private DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames animationLongMsg = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames(); // Animation to move it 

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // move it to the right, at the begin.
            (grdTextblockParent.RenderTransform as TranslateTransform).X = 1000;
        }

        // after click , move the animation
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            animationLongMsg.KeyFrames.Add(new LinearDoubleKeyFrame(-1000, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10)));
            grdTextblockParent.RenderTransform.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, animationLongMsg);
        }
```

Now all fine. the animation is great. But the problem is , the **TextBlock Text not display completely**. It only display until: "This is a test 6". **But I need it display all text when moving** until: "This is a test 10"

I'm not use LayoutTransform because avoid some performance problem. 
Is there any way to fixed it ?  Thank you very much.

Comment: Why are you using an `InlineUIContainer` ? It seems unnecessary.

Comment: @KOTIX, Looks like It generate by visual studio. Sorry for that make you confuse, I'll remove it.

Comment: Increase width of windows.

Comment: @DotNetWeblineindia, I make this sample because My original application has this kind of problem when **full screen**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by myself.
That's because the Grid which is going **animation object required  more long size width parent**.
The problem fixed after I change the XAML to

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
      <!-- Add a new Grid for the animation object parent, and let it more 

long size
           This place is the key
 -->
        <Grid Width="2000">
            <Grid x:Name="grdTextblockParent">
                <Grid.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform  x:Name="grdTransform"/>
                </Grid.RenderTransform>
                <TextBlock x:Name="tb" Text="This is a Test 1This is a Test 2This is a Test 3This is a Test 4This is a Test 5This is a Test 6This is a Test 7This is a Test 8This is a Test 9This is a Test 10" ></TextBlock>

            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Button  Width="75" Height="50" Content="Start" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```